# Waveguides and optical fibres

Tags: electromagnetic, microwave, optical-fibre, waveguide

Why at microwave frequency we prefer rectangular waveguides while at optical frequency circular waveguides (i.e. optical fibres). Can we have rectangular optical fibres.

Comment: Rectangular optical waveguides are built all the time on etched optics on chips. Not so much in long fibres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microwave waveguides are generally made as small as possible while maintaining performance at the frequencies of interest.  This is done by selecting a propagation mode and designing the vertical and horizontal dimensions to allow that mode.  Typically the dimensions are on the order of 3-6 wavelengths of the frequency of interest.  This also offers control of the transmitted signal in other ways, e.g. polarization.

An optical waveguide designed to these standards would be difficult to handle without damage, and likely to twist in inconvenient ways due to the bend radius being different in different radial dimensions.  However, a typical fiber optic cable doesn't need to work in a specific mode for normal industrial uses like communication--just getting the photons to their destination is adequate without worrying about polarization, delay spread, etc.  The relatively disorganized total internal reflection paradigm is thus functionally adequate.

Comment: Agreed. In fact, because of the sensitivity to fiber cable vagaries (rotation, bending, etc) mode mixing is often *added* in order to help encourage still more "disorganization" and therefore still less sensitivity to how someone handled the fiber. I remember, at those odd times when nothing else was handy for the purpose, inserting a piece of wax paper as a temporary "fix" to reduce the sensitivity to cable positioning.

Comment: Delay spread is critical to determining the maximum link distance in many fiber optic communication systems.

Comment: Multimode fiber is primarily used for short range fiber links (e.g. within a building).  Once you want to go longer being single mode is actually critical, otherwise modal dispersion greatly limits your bandwidth while the higher attenuation in MMF limits your SNR.  Even for single mode fibers, the mode properties can be very important at long range because they determine how much nonlinearity will be present.  Of course for typical ethernet these things usually do not matter because bandwidth is low and range is short.

Comment: No. Rectangular RF waveguides are usually just over half a wave in one dimension and *smaller* in the other, so they support precisely one mode, one polarisation. And No, optical fibres are often made small enough that they support only one mode. Called Single Mode fibre. (but they can carry two polarisations as they're circular)

Answer (score 1):

Making a rectangle a few wavelengths wide at optical frequencies would be expensive, but non-circular fibers are used in applications where polarization must be maintained:

[image: PM fiber]

(Taken from the Wikipedia article on polarization-maintaining fiber)

By making the fiber asymmetric, the two axes can be made to have different phase velocities, which will greatly reduce coupling between them. This can be done by physically making the waveguide non-circular or by taking a circular waveguide and adding stress rods to compress one axis relative to the other.

In telecommunications applications you generally prefer a circular fiber though, since attenuation is lower.  Hence PM fiber is primarily used in specialized applications where polarization state must be very well defined.